# Orange Import and process spectra time dependent/kinetics

Tags: orange

I would like to import FTIR spectra that have been collected over time then use Orange to preprocess these as a group. I currently have the spectra as individual SPC or CSV files. How do I import the spectra then plot them as a stack? I have tried using the "Multi-file' widget but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can use the Orange Concatenate Widget under the Data tab shown below:

[image]

This widget takes a primary data set and an additional dataset and concatenates them into one dataset. Once all of your data points are contained in the same dataset, you should have no problem plotting them all together.